# how to setup a wildcard subdomain on 123-reg.co.uk

Tags: domain-name-system, subdomain, wildcard-subdomain

I have a domain on 123-reg.co.uk and I want to setup a **wildcard** subdomain.

I do currently have a * A record which points to one IP address, but I also want a subdomain called `web` which can also use wildcard subdomains.

i.e.

- web.mydomain.com => 1.1.1.1
- example-1.web.mydomain.com => 1.1.1.1
- example-2.web.mydomain.com => 1.1.1.1

While any other subdomains of `mydomain.com` should continue to point to a different IP address `2.2.2.2`

- othersubdomain.mydomain.com => 2.2.2.2

What do I use for the host name in the record? Do I just add `*.web`

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: If you feel the need to redact domain names and IP addresses, please at least do so properly as per [RFC2606](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2606) and [RFC5737](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5737).

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to add two A records

in my case

- `web` to point to 1.1.1.1
- `*.web` to point to 1.1.1.1

If you only add `*.web` then `web.mydomain.com` will not resolve.